# angularjs app: button needs to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple crud app using angularjs. the starting point is a button that fetches data from a rest API and feeds an array that is iterated using `ng-repeat` to create bootstrap cards with the several results. The thing is that, at the beggining, I need to click twice the button so that the cards are displayed, however, despite it makes the `fetch` succesfully and the array to be iterated is filled with data at the first attempt. I can't figure out why this behavior.

Here's the "working" code, can you lend me a hand?

```js
var app = angular.module("myModule", []);

app.controller("firstCtrl", function($scope) {

 $scope.showButton = true;
 $scope.arr;
  $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data) {
     $scope.arr = data.fromServer.results;
     console.log($scope.arr)
  });

  $scope.back = function(){
   $scope.arr = [];
  }

$scope.delPerson = function(person,$index){
  $scope.arr.forEach( personInArray => {
    if(personInArray.id == person.id){
      $scope.arr.splice($index,1)
      console.log($index)
    }
  });
}

$scope.newNameFirst;
$scope.newNameLast;
$scope.p;

$scope.editPerson = function(person, $index){
  $scope.newNameFirst = ""
  $scope.newNameLast = ""
  $scope.p = person
  console.log($scope.p)
}

$scope.reWriteUser = function(){
  $scope.p.name.first= $scope.newNameFirst;
  $scope.p.name.last= $scope.newNameLast;

}

});


app.controller("secondCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.fromServer;   
  $scope.submit = async function() {  
    let one = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=9')
    let two = await one.json();   

    $scope.$emit('myEvent', {
      fromServer: two
    });
    
    $scope.showButton = !$scope.showButton;
  }

});
```

```css
.fa-times-circle:hover{
cursor:pointer;
}

.botones{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.rep{
    background: cadetblue;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Anidando componentes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-app="myModule">

    <!--parent div-->

    <div ng-controller="firstCtrl" class="container">    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-center">
          <h3>Anidando componentes</h3>
      </div>
    </div>  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col rep mt-3" ng-repeat="person in arr">
          <div class="botones">
             <i class="fas fa-times-circle" ng-click="delPerson(person,$index)" ></i>
             <i class="fas fa-edit" ng-click="editPerson(person,$index)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></i>
          </div>  
          <div class="card mt-3" style="width: 10rem;" style="display:inline-block">
              <img src="{{person.picture.thumbnail}}" class="card-img-top" alt="person.name.first">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">{{person.name.first}} {{person.name.last}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!--child div-->
      <div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()" ng-if="showButton">Show users</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="back()" ng-if="!showButton">Back</button>
      </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" name="newName" id="newNameFirst" ng-model="newNameFirst">
          <input type="text" name="newName" id="newNameLast" ng-model="newNameLast">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="reWriteUser()" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    </div>
  </div>

<script src="./app.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of making http requests in Angular.js is using the `$http` service. [as in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Angular.js is a framework that supports real-time change detection using 'The Angular way'. It is not aware of the changes made outside its scope (as while using javascript). You can use manual detection but I woulnd't recommend using it for this specific case.